# XP_FileExists Does Not Work With Network Drives

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am able to run the xp_fileexists command successfully on the local drives of my SQL Server instance.  If a file exists, I get an output of 1.  If a file does not exists, the output is 0.  When I run the same command on a network drive that is mapped on the SQL Server machine, the output is always 0.

For example, if I have a file with a URL of '\\10.188.20.5\myfolder\myfile.txt'.  I would run

```
SET @MYFILE = '\\10.188.20.5\myfolder\myfile.txt'
EXEC MASTER.DBO.XP_FILEEXIST @MYFILE, @MYOUTPUT OUT
PRINT @MYOUTPUT
```

The result would return 0.

If I run a bulk insert command on the same URL, the file would be successfully imported

```
BULK INSERT #mytable
FROM '\\10.188.20.5\myfolder\myfile.txt'
```

What is causing xp_fileexists to malfunction on network drives?

Comment: does the sql server user ID have wrights to access that share/file? just because you do, doesn't mean that mssql does.

Comment: Although bummi's answer below is probably accurate, the most correct answer (in my opinion) is that since the procedure is undocumented you cannot have any expectations about its behaviour. If you rely on undocumented system procedures it's always at your own risk, so if you want something that has the functionality you require, the best solution would be to write a CLR procedure of your own.

Comment: Hi Marc, the server account has access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the Admin account password used to run SQL Server.  The password was changed, but SQL Server continued to run.  It just happened 'MASTER.DBO.XP_FILEEXIST' didn't work because of the password conflict, but other SQL Server functions did.  Once I changed the password associated with the Admin account used to run SQL Server, the function worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the credetials of the Service 
usualy local system, which has not network access

Comment: Hi bummi, the account running SQL Server has network access.  The drive is mapped when logged in as the Administrator (account that runs the service).

Comment: Just try to let run SQL-Server(Service) with an Account with full networkaccess e.g. Domain\Superuser , you will get the wished result.  
Though this makes only sense for a short try ....

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2008, open `Sql Server Configuration Manager`, on left panel go to `SQL Server Services`, on right panel check what user is being used on column `Log On As`for the SQL Server instance you intend to use. In some cases this user would be `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE`. Open `Windows Explorer` and right click the folder you want to give explicit read/write permissions to this user mentioned in `Log On As`.

Answer (score -1):

Go to >> Sql Server Configuration Manager >> on left panel go to SQL Server Services >> select your own Instance (MyPc\Sqlexpress) and enter the account name, the username and the password.

now it should work